# Install Sahara in OpenStack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, openstack

I have already installed OpenStack following the tutorial from [here](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/).

I want to install `Apache Hadoop` on `OpenStack` and I saw [here](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/openstack-savanna-fast-hadoop) that first I have to install `DevStack` before I install `Sahara(Savanna)`

My question are: -

- Is it necessary to install `DevStack`
- Is there any other tutorial for Sahara installation except [this](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/userdoc/installation.guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yup it is better to install Openstack/devstack first which will give you clear picture of the cloud and full controller to your services!!!

On the top of that follow the link which you have posted or you can follow the stable version @ https://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/0.3/ for better community support.

Do share your architecture in case of errors further!!!

Comment: Thanks.. I am trying it now

Answer (score -1):

> Is it necessary to install DevStack

NO!

> Is there any other tutorial for Sahara installation except this.

YES!

By default, i fellow that doc and got various problems.
For example:

1, if you install sahara on ubuntu os, some additional python packages must be installed and this is a missing part in the doc.

2, cluster configuration missing some important options,such as yarn.log.aggration.enabled

3, map-reduce job can not be done, and i use oozie example jar file is okay.

and so on.
[here](http://www.shaunos.com/479.html) is a tutorial, and it is working for me.